# C#: Random.NextDouble and including borders of the custom interval

Tags: c#, random, double

I've used that formula for gettting a random double in custom interval:

```
Random r = new Random();
double Upper = 3.7, Lower = 11.4, Result;    
Result = Lower + (r.NextDouble() * (Upper - Lower))
// Lower is the lower border of interval, Upper is the upper border of interval
```

But keep in mind [what MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.random.nextdouble.aspx) about NextDouble method:

> A double-precision floating point number greater than or equal to 0.0, and less than 1.0.

That means interval in my sample code would include 3.7, but we can never get 11.4, right?
How can I include the upper border?

```
Lower + (r.NextDouble() * (Upper - Lower + double.Epsilon))
```

Can this formula help? Or there is another variant of getting random double numbers in [3.7 ; 11.4] (including both borders) ?

Answer (score 3):

Since your using doubles what kind of precision do you actually use? Rounding the numbers might be enough. Alternatively you can use your own scaling like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var r = new Random(3);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(r.NextDouble(0, 1, 100));
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static double NextDouble(this Random r
    , double lower
    , double upper
    , int scale = int.MaxValue - 1
    )
{
    var d = lower + ((r.Next(scale + 1)) * (upper - lower) / scale);
    return d;
}
```

That will give you the lower and upper inclusive range at the specified scale. I threw in a default value for scale which gives you the highest possible precision, using this method.

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need the upper interval for the double case? The odds of hitting exactly that value are really, really small, and should be statistically insignificant for almost all scenarios. If you're interested in numbers with a certain number of decimal places, then you can use some rounding to achieve what you need.

Comment: The odds of hitting exactly that value are, in fact, often going to be **zero** due to not being able to be exactly expressed using a double....

Comment: What did you mean by "not being able to be exactly expressed using a double"? The probability of getting 11.4(0) is small, but it can be expressed by double, right? :)

Comment: @xaero: No, `11.40` cannot be represented exactly.  Doubles can only represent number of the form z * 2^n, where z is an integer.  So `115 / 16` can be represented, but not `114 / 10`.

Comment: Yes, I know about floating-point number representation format, but never thought about this... You're right :)

Comment: But what derivation function (or something like that) is used to display this number? I've just tried to multiply 11.4*0.63048245614035087719298245614035 and got 115/16 (7,1875).

Answer (score 1):

The precision itself is a problem here, since 3.7 neither 11.4 have a precise double representation.

I think that since you are using random double precision number, I don't think this imprecision is something to care about.

Comment: Why 3.7 neither 11.4 have a precise double representation&

Comment: Sorry, I hitted Enter before time :) Why 3.7 neither 11.4 have a precise double representation? I need such a precision, that's why i've asked this question :)

Comment: Or you're talking about non-lossless projection of 0.0...1.0 to 3.7...11.4 interval?

Comment: Hi, the problem here is that 3.7 is represented as 11.1011001100... note that fractional portion repeats forever, and as double has a limited number of binary digits it can store, it will not be 3.7, but something near 3.7... that is something like 3.69999980926513671875.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following

```
Result = Math.Round(Result, 8)
```

and voila.

The number 8 is the decimal places it will round to. When the random number is within 8 decimal places of the upper bound (example: 11.3999999990) then the result will round to the bound (answer: 11.4000000000).

Of course the round occurs for all the numbers, so choose your precision carefully. It really depends on the application if 8 decimal places is good. Your limits are 1 to 15.

Comment: Why 8? Can you explain this solution more detailed?

Comment: I assumed 8 decimal places is enough. You can go up to 15 I think before this fails.